# How to add Telerik reference just to make work for Telerik datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

Hi guys I am new to Telerik. I am trying to use Telerik `datepicker` in one of my view. I have added couple of references but somehow it is not working. In the following code, Did I miss anything?

```
@{
    Layout = null;

    if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.DefaultPath("~/Content/css3").Add("normalize.css").Add("960.css").Add("fineuploader-3.4.1.css").Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.vista.css").Add("acStyles.css").Add("jquery-ui.css").Add("site.css").Combined(false).CacheDurationInDays(0)).Render();
        Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).jQueryValidation(false).DefaultGroup(group => group.DefaultPath("~/Scripts").Add("jquery.cycle2.js").Add("jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.js").Add("jquery.blockui.js").Add("jquery.tools.js").Add("jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js").Add("jquery.dualListBox-1.3.js").Add("jquery.autocomplete.js").Add("jquery.maskedinput.js").Add("jquery.watermark.js").Add("jquery.validate.js").Add("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js").Add("elmahErrorHandler.js").Add("jquery-ui.js").Combined(false).CacheDurationInDays(0)).Render();
    }
    else
    {
        Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).jQueryValidation(false).DefaultGroup(group => group.DefaultPath("~/Scripts").Add("jquery.cycle2.js").Add("jquery.blockui.js").Add("jquery.tools.js").Add("jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js").Add("jquery.dualListBox-1.3.js").Add("jquery.autocomplete.js").Add("jquery.maskedinput.js").Add("jquery.watermark.js").Add("jquery.validate.js").Add("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js").Add("elmahErrorHandler.js").Add("jquery-ui.js").Combined(true).CacheDurationInDays(1)).Render();
        Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.DefaultPath("~/Content/css3").Add("normalize.css").Add("960.css").Add("fineuploader-3.4.1.css").Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.vista.css").Add("acStyles.css").Add("jquery-ui.css").Add("site.css").Combined(true).CacheDurationInDays(1)).Render();
    }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Wraps those Html.Telerik()... statements into brackets @(Html.Telerik()...) so they can actually be rendered into the output.